# Simplify if statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Is there any Pythonic or compact way to  write the following `if` statement:

```
if head is None and tail is None:
    print("Test")
```

Something like:

```
if (head and tail) is None:
```

Comment: Nope, that's how you write it. Martijn's suggestion will suffice if there are no valid but false-y values (e.g. `''`).

Comment: If there's no chance of the values being falsey for some other reason: `if not head and not tail:`

Comment: Can `head` or `tail` possibly take on any other false-ish value?

Comment: @PM2Ring: oops, indeed.

Comment: Note that `and` short-circuits, so the 2nd test will not be performed if the 1st one fails, i.e., if `head` isn't `None`. So your code is already quite efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If both `head` and `tail` are custom class instances (like `Node()` or similar) without a length or boolean value, then just use:

```
if not (head or tail):
```

This won't work if ether `head` or `tail` could be objects other than `None` with a false-y value (`False`, numeric 0, empty containers, etc.).

Otherwise, you are stuck with the explicit tests. There is no "English grammar" shortcut in boolean logic.

Comment: Note, it will check value is not truthy (not just for `None` value)

Comment: `if not (head or tail)` (or `if not head and not tail`)

Comment: @KirillBulygin: I need more caffeine today.

Answer (score 2):

```
if head is None and tail is None:
    print("Test")
```

is clear and efficient. And if either `head` or `tail` can possibly take false-ish values apart from `None` but you only want `"Test"` to be printed when they're both `None` then what you've written is safer than

```
if not (head or tail):        
    print("Test")
```

A more compact version (than your code) which is still both safe & efficient is

```
if head is None is tail:
    print("Test")
```

`head is None is tail` is actually equivalent to `(head is None) and (None is tail)`. But I think it's a little less readable than your original version.

BTW, `(head and tail) is None` *is* valid Python syntax, but it's not recommended, since it doesn't do what you might at first expect it do:

```
from itertools import product

print('head, tail, head and tail, result')
for head, tail in product((None, 0, 1), repeat=2):
    a = head and tail
    print('{!s:>4} {!s:>4} {!s:>4} {!s:>5}'.format(head, tail, a, a is None))
```

**output**

```
head, tail, head and tail, result
None None None  True
None    0 None  True
None    1 None  True
   0 None    0 False
   0    0    0 False
   0    1    0 False
   1 None None  True
   1    0    0 False
   1    1    1 False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just about as Pythonic as it can be.

When it comes to these things, [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is helpful in remembering that sometimes straightforward is the best option.

```
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, descriptions like `(head and tail) is None` are not allowed in programming for the same reason why `(a and b) = 0` is not allowed in mathematics (to force each statement to have only one, canonical form; "There should be one obvious way to do each thing" is also an [explicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) Python motto).

Comment: What do you mean? `(head and tail) is None` is perfectly valid in Python, but it doesn't do what one might expect it to do. :)

Comment: I certainly mean `(head and tail) is None` written with the same intent as `(a and b) = 0`.